# Using KerasClassifier with fit_generator

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

Is there any way to use `KerasClassifier` with `fit_generator` instead of the regular `fit`?

I have a model for which I'm augmenting the training set on the fly and want to have it as a part of a `sklearn.Pipeline`. I saw that `KerasClassifier` implements `fit` but was wondering whether it's possible to use with `fit_generator` somehow?

My generator is an object that receives several parameters which I want to be able to fine-tune using `GridSearchCV`. Not sure where these should go so `Pipeline` will see them as arguments of the estimator.

Any reason why this wasn't implemented (and therefore I shouldn't waste my time trying to add this)? Any best practices if it is possible somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you resolve this or create your own?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I indeed implemented something on my own. But it was a long time ago, I'd check again if there isn't any other contribution that fixes that.